# What is the easiest way to get statistics on disk usage for my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, disk-space-utilization

I have a SQL Server database with multiple hundreds of data tables in it, and I am looking for disk usage statistics, as it relates to each individual table.

Is there a quick way to find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc Brown [put together a stored procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/mab/archive/2007/07/17/programatic-way-to-determine-space-used-on-all-database-tables.aspx) using the sp_spaceused and sp_tables system stored procedures to gather that information.  Also, if you don't mind using a Microsoft private procedure, [this stored procedure](http://mohitnayyar.blogspot.com/2007/08/get-all-user-defined-table-information.html) is a bit shorter method of accomplishing the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL Server version?
Which 'usage' statistics? Size? Reads? Writes?

For size you look into [`sys.allocation_units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx):

```
select object_name(object_id) as [Object]
 , sum(au.total_pages)*8 as [Size (Kb)]
 from sys.allocation_units au
 join sys.partitions p on au.container_id = p.partition_id
 group by object_id
 having sum(au.total_pages) > 0
```

For IO you look into [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx).

Another possible approach is to enable performance collector sets and use the [SQL Server 2008 Management Data Warehouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939169.aspx).